# Can't add tflite model to React Native project

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, tensorflow, tensorflow-lite

I have created a React Native project using Expo and have a fully functional converted tflite model from keras. I am trying to use the react-native-tensorflow-lite package API to recognize my model a JPEG picture.

[NPM package for React Native Tensorflow lite](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-tensorflow-lite)
I used the exact same template in my expo project, but for some reason the API cannot recognize the model.tflite file path. (See error message in image attachment). [Red Error Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D5lDJ.png)

Below is a copy of how I tried to implement this API using the Expo-Assets library:

```
import {TFLiteImageRecognition} from 'react-native-tensorflow-lite';
import React, {Component} from "react";
import {Text, View, StyleSheet} from "react-native";
import {Asset} from "expo-asset";

//Assets
import Anna from '../../assets/images/anna.jpg';
import Model from '../../android/app/src/main/assets/converted_model.tflite';
import Labels from '../../android/app/src/main/assets/labels.txt';

class MyImageClassifier extends Component {

    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {};

        try {
            // Initialize TensorFlow Lite Image Recognizer
            this.tfLiteImageRecognition = new TFLiteImageRecognition({
                labels: Asset.fromModule(Labels).downloadAsync(),// Your label file in assets folder
                model: Asset.fromModule(Model).downloadAsync()  // Your tflite model in assets folder.
            })
        } catch (err) {
            alert(err)
        }
    }

    /*init (callback) {
        // do something async and call the callback:
        callback.bind(this)();
    }*/

    componentWillMount() {
        let imagePath = Asset.fromModule(require("../../assets/images/anna.jpg"));
        console.warn(imagePath);
        this.classifyImage().then(console.log("Image Classified!"));
    }

    async classifyImage() {
        try {
            const results = await this.tfLiteImageRecognition.recognize({
                image: Asset.fromModule(Anna).downloadAsync(),  // Your image path.
                inputShape: (1, 100, 100, 1), // the input shape of your model. If none given, it will be default to 224.
            });

            const resultObj = {
                name: "Name: " + results[0].name,
                confidence: "Confidence: " + results[0].confidence,
                inference: "Inference: " + results[0].inference + "ms"
            };
            this.setState(resultObj)

        } catch (err) {
            alert(err)
        }
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        this.tfLiteImageRecognition.close() // Must close the classifier when destroying or unmounting component to release object.
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <View>
                    <Text style={styles.results}>
                        {this.state.name}
                    </Text>
                    <Text style={styles.results}>
                        {this.state.confidence}
                    </Text>
                    <Text style={styles.results}>
                        {this.state.inference}
                    </Text>
                </View>
            </View>
        );
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
        paddingTop: 15,
        backgroundColor: '#fff',
    },
    results: {
        fontSize: 22,
        fontFamily: "serif",
        textAlign: 'center'
    }
});

export default MyImageClassifier;
```

I have tested that the file paths accurately point towards the relevant files, so that is definitely not the issue here. I have also validated that my TFLite model can make predictions when passed in input data of the correct shape.

Here is the video I used as a reference to aid me implment the API
[Geeky Ants Tensorflow lite into React Native](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nUbvdhaFNao&t=1068s).

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: one thing I'm noticing is that your input shape is given as a inputShape: (1, 100, 100, 1) as opposed to a single number. I think I remember in documentation it being passed as "inputShape: 224" (where 224 is your shape, which I think would be the product of the height, width and channels?)

Comment: Thanks for the insight @user402516. Im using another approach now, by hosting the model in aws sagemaker and running inferences through there. This question can be closed.